# How to make program go back to the "menu"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Done = False
while not Done:
    print('S Start New Order')
    print('E Edit Order')
    print('P Print Bill')
    print('R Receive Payment')
    print('M Manager Report')
    print('Q Quit')
    print('-----------------')

    Command = ''
    while Command == '':
        Command = input("Enter Choice> ")
        Command = Command.strip().upper()
        if Command[0] == 'S':
            print('Start New Order:')     
        elif Command[0] == 'E':
            print('Edit Order:')
        elif Command[0] == 'P':
            print('Print Bill:')
        elif Command[0] == 'R':
            print('Recieve Payment:')
        elif Command[0] == 'M':
            print('Manager Report:')
        elif Command[0] == 'Q':
            print('Quit:')
```

I want to make it so when someone types for instance "j" or "34", it jumps back to "Enter Choice" and does not display the whole menu all over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. We have to check in entered value.

e.g.

```
while Command not in ['S', 'E','P', 'R', 'M', 'Q']:
    Command = raw_input("Enter Choice> ")
    Command = Command.strip().upper()
```

2. Use `break` statement when user enter `Q` option of Menu. or set value of `Done = True`

e.g.

```
elif Command[0] == 'Q':
    print('Quit:')
    break
```

OR

```
elif Command[0] == 'Q':
    print('Quit:')
    Done = True
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! ok I have one more question: would I have two while statement then? such as having the  while command == "": statement I already have as well as putting the other while statement you said that checks the values?

Comment: also why did u put raw_input? is that a special variable or is it just one you wanted to put?

Comment: I am using python 2.7, `input()` for  `python 3.x` and `raw_input()` for `python 2. x`

Comment: I put the ur while code underneath mine and it worked thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: ok, we need `2 while loops`. First while loop to show Menu options to user after entering valid option. Second while loop to ask user to enter correct option from the Menu again(Not show Menu option).

Comment: welcome :) If you have any more issues and If you want to shear knowledge then I can be reached anytime via email at vivekbsable@gmail.com, for my skype id: vivek.igp.

Answer (score 1):

*Get rid of lines 1 and 2* since "Done" is not used for anything. Add another line at the bottom *"Command = ''"* lined up with the "elseif" to remove stale input. First it prints out the header stuff, then loops around asking for your input, then processing the input, then back to the loop start.